# Picking the first option with exact text capybara

Tags: capybara

```
<select id="profile_idm_sensitivity_set_id" name="profile[idm_sensitivity_set_id]" style="display: inline-block;">
<option value="124"> VC Best Case Virulence  ID</option>
<option value="123"> VC Best Case Virulence  Flu</option>
<option value="122"> VC Best Case Virulence  Flu &amp; ID</option>
<option value="121"> VC Best Case Virulence  ID</option>
</select>
```

I have the following code. But all the time i get element not found on select

```
within('select#profile_idm_sensitivity_set_id') do
    option = find(:option, arg, :exact => true)
    select option, :from => "profile_idm_sensitivity_set_id"
  end
```

How do i select the first option based on text from a select??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
all('#profile_idm_sensitivity_set_id option', :text => 'VC Best Case Virulence').first.click
```

This will click on the first option based on the text that appears in your dropdown.  It looks like you have multiple, identical options there so this should work okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
arg = 'VC Best Case Virulence ID'
select arg, :from => "profile_idm_sensitivity_set_id", :exact => true, :match => :first
```

For the options:

- `:exact => true` will make sure that the option text exactly matches. For example, without this option selecting "VC Best Case Virulence Flu" can match "VC Best Case Virulence Flu" as well as "VC Best Case Virulence Flu & ID". With the option, only "VC Best Case Virulence Flu" will be matched.
- `:match => :first` will result in the first match being selected. With this option, selecting "VC Best Case Virulence ID" will result in the `<option value="124">` being selected. Without the option, the ambiguous match exception would occur (due to `<option value="121">` also having the same text).